# Case statement/form errors?

Tags: common-lisp

```
emacs 29.1
sbcl 2.4.0 
slime 2.29.1
```

Here's my function:

```
(defun my-case ()
  (case 'a
    (b "hello")
    (a "world")
    (otherwise "mars")))
```

When I compile it, `C-c C-k`, I see the following in the mini-buffer:

[image]

In the slime repl, I see:

```
; processing (DEFUN MY-CASE ...)

; file: /var/tmp/slimeckqotJ
; in: DEFUN MY-CASE
;     (CASE 'A (B "hello") (A "world") (OTHERWISE "mars"))
; --> COND IF PROGN 
; ==>
;   "hello"
; 
; note: deleting unreachable code

; --> COND IF IF THE PROGN 
; ==>
;   "mars"
; 
; note: deleting unreachable code
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   printed 2 notes
```

And, in my source file, the word "case" is underlined:

[image]

However, my function runs fine:

```
CL-USER> (my-case)
"world"
```

What are "notes"?

Comment: Normally M-n and M-p should navigate between notes and show their message in the minibuffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notes are telling you that the clauses `(b "hello")` and `(otherwise "mars")` are unreachable.

The first argument to a `case` form is evaluated to produce a key for testing the clauses. In `my-case` that keyform argument always evaluates to the symbol `a`, so the compiler can see that there is only one possible result.

A `case` form is not much use when there is only one possible outcome. Here is a version that does not trigger the compiler notes and removal of unreachable code:

```lisp
(defun my-case (&optional (k 'a))
   (case k
     (b "hello")
     (a "world")
     (otherwise "mars")))
```

```
CL-USER> (my-case)
"world"
CL-USER> (my-case 'b)
"hello"
CL-USER> (my-case 'needs-guitars)
"mars"
```